# Java native query - com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLSyntaxErrorException

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, nativequery

I get following error: "com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLSyntaxErrorException: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near 'Card.findPrefix'"

```
for:

    @NamedNativeQueries({
        @NamedNativeQuery(name = "Card.findPrefix",
                query = "SELECT DISTINCT(FLOOR(c

    .number/10000)) FROM Card c")
    })

    public List<Integer> findPrefix(){
            Query q = em.createNativeQuery("Card.findPrefix");
            try{
                return q.getResultList();
            }catch(Exception ex){
                ex.printStackTrace();
                return null;
            }
        }
```

I can not understand where is my mistake, because when I type this query directly to Mysql it works perfectly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use should use createNamedQuery, instead of createNativeQuery.

From [EntityManager JavaDoc](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/persistence/EntityManager.html)

**createNativeQuery(String sqlString)**

Create an instance of Query for executing a native SQL statement, e.g., for update or delete.

**createNamedQuery(String name)**

Create an instance of Query for executing a named query (in the Java Persistence query language or in native SQL).

So in your code you are executing query name 'Find....' as SQL query.

The right one:

```
Query q = em.createNamedQuery("Card.findPrefix");
```

Answer (score 0):

Final code is:

```
public List<Integer> findPrefix(){
        Query q = em.createNamedQuery("Card.findPrefix");
        List<Integer> res = new ArrayList<Integer>();
        for(Object row : (List<Object>) q.getResultList()){
            res.add(((BigInteger)row).intValue());
        }
        return res;
    }
    @NamedNativeQueries({
    @NamedNativeQuery(name = "Card.findPrefix",
            query = "SELECT DISTINCT(FLOOR(c.number/10000)) FROM Card c")
})
```